# Handling void pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, void-pointers

I'm making a C code to handle sparse matrixes, and i want to modularize my code at its maximum.

I noticed that there are a couple times when i need to walk-until-i-find-the-previous-node (oh, i am using linked lists to build the matrix), and i want to make a reusable function.

I have 4 structs in my code, all of them have the vars `first`, `last` or `next` if is a child structure that have no header-role.

I thought a code like this:

```
void *iterateUntilNext(void *header, void *child)
{
    void *walker = header->first;
    while (walker->next != child)
    {
        walker = walker->next;
    }
    return walker;
}
```

But i got this error: `expression must have pointer-to-struct-or-union type but it has type "void *"`

Is there any way to make this work or am i dreaming too much?

Comment: Cast it to the pointer of the type which it is expected to be pointing to. Or work with this type instead of `void*`  all the way down.

Comment: So there is not any way to make it full reusable, right? I will try casting it like you said :)

Comment: How pointer to no type can have members. Muy advice - do not try to be too universal. It never works.

Comment: `header` points to an unknown type, how will the compiler know what this `first` field is?

Comment: To be reusable, there is a way with function like macros. The 'problem' with that is the need to provide a type as argument. GCC (and friends) do have a nice extension like `typeof` or `__auto_type` to avoid that.

Comment: The usual pattern to make "generic" data types is to provide the access and other operations at a time of creating the data structure. But it is a relatively broad topic to be covered in comments. Maybe someone would write it upas an answer...

Comment: @0___________ well i am sorry if my question does not contribute to the community. Indeed i am kinda new in C. If y'all think that the question must be closed, i'll close it. But notice that there's not a single person that borns knowing eveerything. Also have in mind that your last comment was not that polite. But thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: @JoãoPedroMartinsdePaula simply think on your program, not try to create universal functions. It never works and at the end of the day, it creates more problem that is solves. But as I wrote, it is a normal childhood disease and probably every single programmer (including myself) was trying to code something ultra super universal and abstract in not suitable languages. Higher abstraction levels have to be supported by the language itself - for example as C++ does

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the advice ;)

Comment: You could use intrusive lists. See https://www.data-structures-in-practice.com/intrusive-linked-lists/

Comment: What if you pass in a pointer to a "first" and "next" function?  Then you don't need to know the type.  This is how qsort works with the compare function.  https://onlinegdb.com/f9CCbkpt6

Answer (score 0):

**OOP**

Define a base struct like

```
#define list_item_interface \
  list_item *first; \
  list_item *next;

typedef struct list_item {
    list_item_interface
} list_item;
```

and 'derive' your custom items like

```
typedef struct custom_list_item {
    list_item_interface //needs to be the first entry
    //other members/fields
} custom_list_item;
```

then define your 'generic' functions like

```
list_item* iterate(list_item *header, list_item *child) { /*...*/ }
```

call it like

```
custom_list_item *header, *child;
iterate((list_item*) header, (list_item*) child);
```

---

**GCC - Extension**

Accepts any type, which provides the fields `first` and `next` of the same type.

```
#define LIST_ITEM_ITERATE(HEADER, CHILD) ({ \
    __auto_type HEADER_ = (HEADER); \
    __auto_type CHILD_  = (CHILD); \
    __auto_type WALKER  = HEADER_->first; \
    while (WALKER->next != CHILD_) \
        WALKER = WALKER->next; \
    WALKER; \
)}
```

Comment: UB - strict aliasing rules.

Comment: @0___________ What about C11 Standard, section 6.5 Expressions, paragraph 7: _an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union)_. Like: `struct custom_list_item { list_item *base; /*...*/ };`